# How to declare the spring bean during its initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I need to do something like this.

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean class="com.example.Converter1"/>
            <bean class="com.example.Converter2"/>
            <bean id="converter3" class="com.example.Converter3"/>
            <bean id="converter4" class="com.example.Converter4">
                <property name="conversionService" ref="converter3"/>
            </bean>
            <bean id="converter5" class="com.example.Converter5">
                <property name="conversionService" ref="converter4"/>
            </bean>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I want to use converter3 bean into converter4 bean via @Autowired annotation. Can I do this or it is bad way for programming?

Please, help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to convert the `converter3` and `converter4`  parts of this XML configuration into an equivalent `@Autowired` configuration? What do you mean by _bad way of programming_? What makes you think it would be wrong/bad?

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you want, but in case you mean to inject instance of converter3 into converter4 class using @Autowired it's OK.